# QField merging geometries not possible with Geopackage-Features

Tags: merge, geopackage, qfield

When working with shapefiles, it is possible to merge selected polygons; but I wasn't able to do this with Geopackage features. I can do multiple selections, but the "merge" option is inactive.
Are there any limiations for geopackages?

Comment: Are you using multipolygons in your GeoPackage?

Comment: I experienced the same issue and I have no multipolygons. Any suggestions?